# Heroku deploy branch failed

Tags: github, heroku, discord, bots

I have a problem with Heroku, I'm trying to build my own discord bot and I followed a tutorial https://youtu.be/8qIsRzV0Hpg but I had a problem and couldn't deploy it, this is the error:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.15.4...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.10
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       
       > @discordjs/opus@0.4.0 install /tmp/build_12ef9cfb_/node_modules/@discordjs/opus
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 126
       npm ERR! @discordjs/opus@0.4.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 126
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the @discordjs/opus@0.4.0 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Lv9o4/_logs/2021-02-09T14_07_39_023Z-debug.log
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - node_modules checked into source control
           
       - Node version not specified in package.json
              
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://help.heroku.com/YSSC5AXQ/why-is-my-node-build-running-into-a-permission-denied-error ?

Comment: It would be helpful to add the complete log for this error as the message says. You can find it in `/tmp/npmcache.Lv9o4/_logs/2021-02-09T14_07_39_023Z-debug.log`

Comment: `Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)` did you commit `node_modules/` to your git repo? If so remove that. --- @Shunya Heroku creates temporary Dynos. He doesn't have access to the machine. It's not a VPS. It's immediately destroyed after it fails a build. So he won't be able to access that

Comment: I solved it by simply deleting the node_modules folder from the project :)